# Please help me to find the error in this YII Transaction code

Tags: transactions, yii

I have a huge form and I want to save my form to 5 different tables and I want to make sure that the data saves to all 5 tables, for this I am trying to use Yii Transations but it's not working for me, please have a look at below code to figure out the bug.

```
$ParentModel->attributes = $_POST['ParentModel'];
$firstChild->attributes = $_POST['FirstChild'];
$secondChild->attributes = $_POST['SecondChild'];
$thirdChild->attributes = $_POST['ThirdChild'];
$fourthChild->attributes = $_POST['FourthChild'];

if($ParentModel->validate())
{
    $transaction = $ParentModel->dbConnection->beginTransaction(); // Transaction begin
    try{
        $ParentModel->save(); // saving parent model

        //parent_id is required for all models

        $firstChild->parent_id = $ParentModel->id;
        $secondChild->parent_id = $ParentModel->id;
        $thirdChild->parent_id = $ParentModel->id;
        //$fourthChild->parent_id = $ParentModel->id; I commented this line so that fourth child throw an exception on $fourthChild->save() becuase parent_id is required


        $firstChild->save();    
        $secondChild->save();
        $thirdChild->save();
        $fourthChild->save(); // fourth child is not saved here, transction should throw exception

        $transaction->commit();    // committing 

        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$ParentModel->id));    // Redirecting on user creation
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        $transaction->rollBack();
    }
}
```

Above code doesn't throwing any exception and data for fourth table lost due to validation rules failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii doesn't throw an exception when [saving to a model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail).

You need to add your own error checking after saving, probably something like this (untested):

```
if($ParentModel->validate())
{
    $transaction = $ParentModel->dbConnection->beginTransaction(); // Transaction begin
    try{
        $ParentModel->save(); // saving parent model

        //parent_id is required for all models

        $firstChild->parent_id = $ParentModel->id;
        $secondChild->parent_id = $ParentModel->id;
        $thirdChild->parent_id = $ParentModel->id;
        //$fourthChild->parent_id = $ParentModel->id; I commented this line so that fourth child throw an exception on $fourthChild->save() becuase parent_id is required

        $results = array()
        $results[] = $firstChild->save();    
        $results[] = $secondChild->save();
        $results[] = $thirdChild->save();
        $results[] = $fourthChild->save(); // fourth child is not saved here, transction should throw exception

        foreach($results as $result) {
           if (!$result) { throw new Exception('error') }
        }

        $transaction->commit();    // committing 

        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$ParentModel->id));    // Redirecting on user creation
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        $transaction->rollBack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 of the above code you have:

```
$fourthChild-->attributes = $_POST['FourthChild'];
```

It should be

```
$fourthChild->attributes = $_POST['FourthChild'];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that is not the issue, question updated. Please check